# Printing .MSG files

Tags: powershell, printing, msg

I have a User who needs to print off over 600 .msg files. I figured it would be easier to find a script which I run and it goes through all of the files and prints them off. I found this script online:

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\folder\*.msg" |
    ForEach-Object { Start-Process $_.FullName -Verb Print }
```

Now this works great but it only print 24 files at anyone time. Is there a way to increase the this limit so it will run through all 600?

Comment: Could you try putting -wait on the end of Start-Process, so that it waits for each file to print before moving onto the next?

Comment: That has worked perfectly. Thanks